# PHP chart - Filling in missing dates with values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, charts

I am currently working on a chart, displaying my budget relative to the corresponding date.

All transactions are stored in a SQL database.

I use the following SQL query to extract the total amount per day *(pd)* for each date *(date)*:

```
SELECT date, round(sum(amount),2) as 'pd' FROM money_transactions GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

This gives me a result looking like:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    |   pd   |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-11-25 | 4.89   |
| 2017-12-01 | 90.00  |
| 2017-12-02 | -40.00 |
+------------+--------+
```

Now, I want it to look this way:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    |   pd   |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-11-25 | 4.89   |
| 2017-11-26 | 0.00   |
| 2017-11-27 | 0.00   |
| 2017-11-28 | 0.00   |
| 2017-11-29 | 0.00   |
| 2017-11-30 | 0.00   |
| 2017-12-01 | 90.00  |
| 2017-12-02 | -40.00 |
+------------+--------+
```

If there is a day without a transaction, I want the total amount pd *(per day)* to be 0, because there is no movement on the account.

**Is there any SQL way of doing this?** Or would it be smarter to do it in PHP, once there is no additional SQL calculation time needed (making the web application smoother).

If so, do you know how I could do this in PHP?

My chart code looks this way:

```
var ctxL = document.getElementById("chart_all_transactions").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [
            <?php
                foreach($results as $value) {
                    $transaction_chart_date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($value["date"]));
                    echo '"'.$transaction_chart_date.'"'.",";
                }
            ?>
],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Budget",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [
                    <?php
                    $interim = 0;
                    foreach($results as $value) {
                        $interim += $value["pd"];
                        echo $interim.",";
                    }
                    ?>
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }    
});
```

So for each Label (date) there is a corresponding Dataset (pd). If I use PHP to generate missing dates **(Labels)** and insert it in the array, how does the **Datasets** know what date the amount of money is corresponding to?

Would be awesome, if any of you would know a solution (SQL or PHP) to this problem.

Appreciating any help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem using SQL!**

Please note, that this is not the best solution. A PHP solution would be much faster when it comes to processing and CPU time. The query does its job, but the performance is not great.

The query:

```
SELECT c.mydate AS alldate, SUM( IF( t.account LIKE :acc, COALESCE( ROUND( t.amount, 2 ) , 0 ) , 0 ) ) AS pd
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN money_transactions t ON t.date = c.mydate
WHERE c.mydate >= STR_TO_DATE(  "2013-12-01",  "%Y-%m-%d" ) 
AND c.mydate <= ( 
SELECT MAX( c.mydate ) 
FROM calendar c
JOIN money_transactions t ON t.date = c.mydate ) 
GROUP BY c.mydate
ORDER BY c.mydate
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, doing this at the database level would be more complicated. Besides, it would also mean moving around extra meaningless data between the database and the application. So, I would do this in php. If you have a `$startDate` and `$endDate`, you can loop over all the dates between them. For example, in the `data` property in the javascript, you could write something like:

```
$interim = 0;
$i = 0;
$date = $startDate;
while($date <= $endDate){
    if($i < count($results) && strtotime($results[$i]["date"]) == $date){
        $value = $results[$i]["pd"];
        $i++;
    } else {
        $value = 0;
    }
    $interim += $value;
    echo $interim;

    $date = $date + 24*60*60
}
```

I think it would be better to previously create a date-value dictionary, so you don't depend on the rows being ordered by date, and the code in the chart would look a bit neater, but it would still work like this.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd do (or something like it, anyway£

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find the end date of a month using [LAST_DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) and pre-fill those dates to zero values. Write a small code to find all dates between your range, sort them if your data exists.